# Running bash script from pipeline always hangs

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've created a simple pipeline which is attempting to run a script and then I'll do something else with the output, however the script (CheckTagsDates.sh) never finishes according to Jenkins. If I SSH into the Jenkins slave node, su as the jenkins user, navigate to the correct workspace folder, I can execute the command successfully.

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'agent'}
    stages {
        stage('Check for releases in past 24hr') {
            steps{
                sh 'chmod +x CheckTagsDates.sh'
                script {
                    def CheckTagsDates = sh(script: './CheckTagsDates.sh', returnStdout: true)
                    echo "${CheckTagsDates}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the contents of the CheckTagsDates.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
        array[ $i ]="$line"
        (( i++ ))
done < <( curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/centos/tags'|jq -r '."results"[] | "\(.name)&\(.last_updated)"')

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
        echo $i | cut -d '&' -f 1
        echo $i | cut -d '&' -f 2
done
```

Here is the output from the script in the console

```
latest
2020-01-18T00:42:35.531397Z
centos8.1.1911
2020-01-18T00:42:33.410905Z
centos8
2020-01-18T00:42:29.783497Z
8.1.1911
2020-01-18T00:42:19.111164Z
8
2020-01-18T00:42:16.802842Z
centos7.7.1908
2019-11-12T00:42:46.131268Z
centos7
2019-11-12T00:42:41.619579Z
7.7.1908
2019-11-12T00:42:34.744446Z
7
2019-11-12T00:42:24.00689Z
centos7.6.1810
2019-07-02T14:42:37.943412Z
```

Comment: Only based on my previous pipelines, did you try replacing "echo CheckTagsDates" by echo "${CheckTagsDates}". Honestly, is the only thing that seems be weird

Comment: Updated. The .sh script still runs forever and never exits according to jenkins.

Comment: are you getting any output whatsoever on the Jeknins console? meaning, is the script getting stuck on the obtention of data? or after it has echoed all the info

Answer (score 1):

How I told you in a comment, I think that is a wrong use of the echo instruction for string interpolation.

Jenkins Pipeline uses rules identical to Groovy for string interpolation. Groovy’s String interpolation support can be confusing to many newcomers to the language. While Groovy supports declaring a string with either single quotes, or double quotes, for example:

```
def singlyQuoted = 'Hello'
def doublyQuoted = "World"
```

Only the latter string will support the dollar-sign ($) based string interpolation, for example:

```
def username = 'Jenkins'
echo 'Hello Mr. ${username}'
echo "I said, Hello Mr. ${username}"
```

Would result in:

```
Hello Mr. ${username}
I said, Hello Mr. Jenkins
```

Understanding how to use string interpolation is vital for using some of Pipeline’s more advanced features.

Source: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation

Comment: Thank you for this, I really appreciate it. While this will satisfy an error for the ECHO command, the issue I reported is still present, with the .sh script never exiting according to Jenkins.

Comment: Each run of job, jenkins create a temporary directory with the number of job. Is the file script really there?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for this case, I would suggest you to do the parsing of the json content in Groovy, instead of shell, and limit the script to only retrieving the json.

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'agent'}
    stages {
        stage('Check for releases in past 24hr') {
            steps{
                script {
                    def TagsDates = sh(script: "curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/centos/tags'", returnStdout: true).trim()
                    TagsDates = readJSON(text: TagsDates)
                    TagsDates.result.each {
                        echo("${it.name}")
                        echo("${it.last_updated}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```